# What expects lintian when it returns missing-dependency-on-libc when building a debian package

Tags: unix, debian, packaging, vala

When I try to build my vala application with `debuild -i -us -uc -b`, the packages are built but **lintian** complains that my control file missed a dependency to `libc` :

```
E: <my app>: missing-dependency-on-libc needed by <path to my binary>
```

**What should add to the my depends section?**

```
Source: <my_app>
Section: x11
Priority: optional
Maintainer: <me>
Build-Depends: cmake (>= 2.8),
               debhelper (>= 9),
               libgee-0.8-dev,
               libglib2.0-dev,
               valac (>= 0.22)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: <my_website>
```

Comment: Can you should the binary package section of your `control` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @apmasell, the issue came from the the section below the one that I included in the question.

I forgot to add

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}
```

to my binary packages.

Comment: And the rationale is explained at https://lintian.debian.org/tags/missing-dependency-on-libc.html:

"All shared libraries and compiled binaries must be run through `dpkg-shlibdeps` to find out any libraries they are linked against (often via the `dh_shlibdeps debhelper` command). The package containing these files must then depend on `${shlibs:Depends}` in `debian/control` to get the proper package dependencies for those libraries."